# Sort method is only sorting appended strings but not the strings that were initially in array

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I am trying to have a button that saves whats in the textfields then adds them to their arrays, then sorts the arrays. However, whenever the sort occurs, the first two strings in my array aren't sorted, but the third and anything else saved is.

Here are the arrays

```
//Array holding Names
var names: [String] =
  [

    "Alexander Jones",
    "Tony Stark",
    "cap"

  ]

//Array holding emails
var emails: [String] =
  [

    "alex@fiu.edu",
    "Tony@Stark.com",
    "cap@ca"

  ]

//Index to move through arrays
var index: Int = 0
```

and here is the button function (please ignore the update section of it, I am trying to get sort to work before I tackle that

```
@IBAction func updateButtonPressed(_ sender :UIButton)
  {

    var name = nameField.text
    let email = emailField.text

    print("0 \(names)")
    print("0 \(emails)")

    //if the email or name isn't modified
    //assume user is updating card
    if (name==names[index]) || (email==emails[index])
    {
        //if both textfileds are same as index, update since values will stay the same
        //if one filed is updated at the current index, it will be changed at the index and
        //still match the index of other array
        names[index]=name!
        emails[index]=email!

    }
    else
    {
        //if user puts a new value for both
        //we assume it is a new entry and add it to list
        names.append(name!)
        emails.append(email!)
        print("After Add")
        print("1 \(names)")
        print("1 \(emails)")

        //sort list in alphabetical after each update/save

        names = names.sorted(by: <)
        print("After sorted by name")
        print("2 \(names)")
        print("2 \(emails)")

        //find index new name is sorted too
        //and place new email in same index
        //of emailarray
        let newindex = names.index(of:name!)
        //emails.remove(at: index)
        emails.insert(email!, at: newindex!)
        print("After email insert")
        print("3 \(names)")
        print("3 \(emails)")
    }

  }
```

Comment: Why don't you use a struct containing name and email of one person rather than two arrays? The code is pretty cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason why your names aren't sorted how you've expected is that within string sorting, big characters came first

```
B, a, c
```

to avoid this behaviour, you can lowercase `String` using `lowercased()`

---

Anyway, don't have two separate arrays. Have just one of your custom model. So, first create your custom model using `struct`

```
struct Person {
    var name, email: String
}
```

and then create array of people

```
var people = [Person(name: "Alexander Jones", email: "alex@fiu.edu"),
              Person(name: "Tony Stark", email: "Tony@Stark.com"), 
              Person(name: "cap", email: "cap@ca")]
```

Then just after pressing button append new `Person` and sort all elements by their lowercased `name`

```
@IBAction func updateButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    people.append(Person(name: nameField.text!, email: emailField.text!))
    people.sort { $0.name.lowercased() < $1.name.lowercased() }
}
```

---

You can also add `didSet` observer to you array and then your array will be sorted every time that some new element will be appended or array will be changed somehow

```
var people = [Person(name: "Alexander Jones", email: "alex@fiu.edu"),
              Person(name: "Tony Stark", email: "Tony@Stark.com"), 
              Person(name: "cap", email: "cap@ca")] {
    didSet {
        people.sort { $0.name.lowercased() < $1.name.lowercased() }
    }
}
...
@IBAction func updateButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    people.append(Person(name: nameField.text!, email: emailField.text!))
}
```

---

Last thing, if you need to sort your array before first pressing button, don't forget to sort it for example in controller's `viewDidLoad`

Comment: For completeness: You are not handling the updating part where either name or mail is already there.

Comment: Wow I don't think I ever noticed that case was an issue it was driving me crazy thank you. And again thank you for a more manageable way to do this. I'm very new to this so only have limited exposure to what I can do outside of the book I follow.